# Grouping data from on Raw Data table to another based om Max value pr. houer

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by, aggregate-functions

I really hope someone can help me out on this tricky problem.

I have a table that constantly is receiving data (like a data log)
The table is receiving data 24*7.
There can be many records pr. Hour and many Name A,B,C,D etc.

Table RAW

```
LogTime               Name   Value  
2015-05-16 00:29:00     A       03  
2015-05-16 00:48:00     A       15      
2015-05-16 00:29:00     B       30  
2015-05-16 00:35:00     B       32  
2015-05-16 00:59:00     B       66          
2015-05-16 01:25:11     A       88  
2015-05-16 01:52:00     A       100  
2015-05-16 01:26:45     B       5  
2015-05-16 01:57:00     B       51
```

Every day after midnight I want to run a procedure that goes back to the previous day
XXXX-XX-XX 00:00:00 to the  XXXX-XX-XX 23:59:59.
Take the MAX value for each Name, group by Hour, and insert the result into another table, with the following format

Table Result

```
TimeByHouer            Name     Value  
2015-05-08 01:00:00      A         15  
2015-05-08 01:00:00      B         66  
2015-05-08 02:00:00      A         100  
2015-05-08 02:00:00      B         51
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are requesting help with. Please clarify what you wish to accomplish and demonstrate what you have already attempted including any relevant code.

Comment: I just edited your question to improve the readability.

Comment: Sorry, but i couldent find out to format the table in the forum, i have adde in ______ for instead of Tabulation, hope that clears it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
declare @t table(logtime datetime, name char(1), value int)
insert into @t(logtime, name, value) values
('2015-05-16 00:29:00', 'A', 3),
('2015-05-16 00:48:00', 'A', 15),
('2015-05-16 00:29:00', 'B', 30),  
('2015-05-16 00:35:00', 'B', 32), 
('2015-05-16 00:59:00', 'B', 66),    
('2015-05-16 01:25:11', 'A', 88), 
('2015-05-16 01:52:00', 'A', 100), 
('2015-05-16 01:26:45', 'B', 5),
('2015-05-16 01:57:00', 'B', 51)

; with Hs(TimeByHouer, name, value) as (
Select H = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, logtime), DATEPART(MONTH, logtime), DATEPART(DAY, logtime), DATEPART(HOUR, logtime), 0, 0, 0)
, name, value From @t
)
Select TimeByHouer, name, Max(value) From Hs Group By TimeByHouer, name
Order By TimeByHouer, name
```

with 2012 you can also use:

```
Select DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, logtime), cast(cast(logtime as date) as datetime))
```

Comment: Simply fantastic :-), it works really good. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: I tested it fist :) Can you plese accept my answer. Thanks